# How to match words in which must be letter, number and slash using regex (Python)?

Tags: python, regex

I have such list (it's only a part);

```
not match me
norme
16/02574/REMMAJ
20160721
17/00016/FULM
OUT/2017/1071
SMD/2017/0391
17/01090/FULM
2017/30597
17/03940/MAO
18/00076/FULM
CH/17/323
18/00840/OUTMEI
17/00902/EIAM
PL/2017/02671/MINFOT
```

I need to find general rule to match them all but not this first rows (simple words) or any of `\d` nor `\w` if not mixed with each other and slash. Numbers like `\d{8}` are allowed.

I don't know how to use something like MUST clause applied for each of these 3 groups together - neither can be miss.

These patterns either match not fully or match words. Need as simple regex as possible if possible.

`\d{8}|(\w+|/+|\d+)`
`\d{8}|[\w/\d]+`

**EDIT**

It's funny, but some not provided examples doesn't match for proposed expressions. For example:

```
7/2018/4127 
NWB/18CM032
```

but I know why and this is outside the scope. However, adding functionality for mixed numbers and letters in one group, like `NWB/18CM032` would be great and wouldn't break previous idea I think.

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^(?:[A-Z]+|\d{1,8})(?:/(?:[A-Z]+|\d{1,8}))*$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/7m6msS/1)

Comment: This works for the idea. Thanks. However, it's a problem. I said it can't match single word like `word`.

Comment: This [regex](https://regex101.com/r/gl7JH0/2/) will match at least the structure with a forward slash, this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/gl7JH0/3) will also match mixed numbers and letters and is using the case insensitive flag.

Comment: First doesn't match `WDC/18CM005` so this second one will be the final answer (as just checked all the long list). Thanks!

Comment: Great that the last one works! I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match either 1 or more times an uppercase char or 1-8 digits and repeat that zero or more times with a forward slash prepended:

```
^(?:[a-z0-9]+(?:/[a-z0-9]+)+|\d{8})$
```

That will match

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[a-z0-9]+` Match a char a-z or a digit 1+ times
  - `(?:/[a-z0-9]+)+` Match a `/` followed by a char or digit 1+ times and repeat 1+ times.
  - `|` Or
  - `\d{8}` Match 8 digits
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

See it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7m6msS/1)